# Run a local command before starting eclipse debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I want to run a terminal command just before a debug configuration starts on Eclipse.
I heard about CDT launch Groups, but couldnt get around it fully. I need to just run a normal terminal command, nothing fancy.

The aim is to copy some stuff over to the execution path before actually starting the debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this via "Launch Groups" in the CDT. Creating 2 groups, one as a c/C++ Application which calls a shell script that includes the command I want to run. And then the normal debug configuration I wanted to execute.