# How to develop/test for a system that must run locally but cannot be run on the development OS

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, remote-debugging

I'm a Java developer used to using Maven to do unit/integration tests for web services. Right now, I have a client library that I need to test that does everything using local references. So, for example, it looks for needed files and applications on whatever box it is running on. However, those are Linux boxes and I have a Windows development ecosystem.

Currently, the hacky way I've been doing testing of the code is create a main class with various methods that test different things. Obviously, this doesn't use any of the JUnit framework or anything like that. As part of my maven build, I can deploy the jar out to the Linux box and then run the jar's main class and remote debug. This allows me to actually use my Windows OS and IDE and still development.

However, when it comes to testing, I don't see an easy way to development in Windows when I want to run the code in Linux. I know I could put Maven on the Linux box and use some text editor to actually develop but given my complete lack of expertise in Linux, I think it would go extremely slowly, especially when I would need to debug anything. I also don't believe there's other areas of my work where such knowledge would be that useful, so it would be a lot of investment for small return.

Does anyone have ideas on a better to approach this issue? Ideally I'd like to be able to remote debug into tests that can run on the Linux box. Or at least a better solution than what I'm doing now.

Comment: If Java on Windows process Unix path like "/tmp/file1.txt" it will find file if location is "C:\tmp\file1.txt". So you can place required file in convinient Windows location

Comment: It's more than just files, though, it's a running application on Linux that I can't run on Windows.

Comment: Visual studio code and IntelliJ can work on remote machines

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you mean unit test development with windows but for a lib which requires linux environment.

Maybe your IDE can do work before they start something. You could start a script in WSL linux which compiles and starts your software in wsl with remote debug port open. Then the DEBUG config contains a remote session to the software in WSL. The IDE can do a post job, too. Here you stop the running instance. So you could automate it a bit.

See also : [Run a local command before starting eclipse debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217614/run-a-local-command-before-starting-eclipse-debugging)